# Why compiler in Visual Studio doesn't allow to pass argument int N[a][b], int M[b][a] to function?

Tags: c, arrays

Why compiler in Visual Studio doesn't allow to pass argument int N[a][b], int M[b][a] to function? At the same time this technic are allowed in Linux?

This code works on Linux ( I use https://ide.cs50.io and I don't know which version of compiler there are). But it dosen't work in VS on Windows.
And I'm wondering why it is that? 
It says cannot allocate an array of constant size 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// I need to change it to N[4][5], int M[5][4] then it works in VS
void transposeMatrix(int a, int b, int N[a][b], int M[b][a]) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            M[j][i] = N[i][j];
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int a = 4, b = 5;

    int M[5][4] =
    {
        { 0, 10, 22, 30 },
        { 4, 50, 6, 77 },
        { 80, 9, 1000, 111 },
        { 12, 130, 14, 15 },
        { 16, 17, 102, 103 }

    };

    int N[4][5] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
    };

    printf("array  M\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            printf("%8i", M[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    transposeMatrix(a, b, N, M);

    printf("array  M\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            printf("%8i", M[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work in VS"? Can you post the errors/warnings or whatever that it shows?

Comment: Linux doesn't compile programs. A compiler does. I'm gonna guess you use GCC. Either way, what you suggest is not correct C, so don't try to reason with it. Compiler probably allows it as an extension.

Comment: @DeiDei The code shown is valid conforming C code.

Comment: @2501 I can't get three compilers to compile `void f(int a, int b, int c[a][b]);`. Got proof it's conforming?

Comment: I use https://ide.cs50.io I don't know which version of compiler there are. Thank you! @DeiDei

Comment: @DeiDei You're either using a compiler that 17+ years old, or it isn't conforming.

Comment: VS http://pho.to/AZVvM  Linux http://pho.to/AZVvS @P.P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called variable-length array, it is standard in C99 (although it's not a recommended feature). The problem is just that VS doesn't support C99.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Right they became optional in C11. Not a great loss though.

Comment: I am wondering why my comment has been removed, that said VLAs are optional in C11.

Answer (score -2):

The parameters for a function can never be values in its declaration. They are only ways to reference the values passed into the function when it is called in the program.

You should rewrite the declaration of the `transposeMatrix` function to be

```
void transposeMatrix(int a, int b, int** N, int** M)
```

because the N and M that you want to use as function parameters are two-dimensional arrays.

Not sure actually why this works on Linux, it's not the way a program should be written. Maybe someone else can clarify why it might work there.

Comment: I hope that worked for you @Yellowfun. If it did could you mark my response as the correct answer thanks :) if you still have a problem, I'd be happy to provide whatever other help I can

Comment: This is obviously wrong since arrays of arrays aren't pointers to pointers. Arrays M and N cannot be passed to this function.

Comment: Arrays of arrays can be represented and are represented in the above code as pointers to pointers.

Comment: If the `**` is supposed to be a 2D array as in `main` then the function cannot know the row length from this declaration. A 2D array is not an array of pointers to pointers.

Comment: `a` and `b` are the width and height of the array, the other parameters in the function

Comment: @ChobChub Look, it is obvious that you're not listening to our comments explaining that your answer is wrong. So, here's what you should do. Write a small code example using the function in your answer and arrays Yellowfun defined in his example. You are not allowed to change the definitions of those arrays. Then enable compiler warnings and try to compile your code. Deal?